# vectors and arc length

Tags: functions

I have a short questions. I have two functions that describe an arc. One describes the vertical movement, one the horizontal movement. If we say that 
$$
y(x)= C_1\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2L}} \\
z(x)= C_2\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}
$$
this gives me a nice cosine curve when plotted. However when I try to find the arc length, I get a value that is smaller than the original $L$. How is this possible? Cu is very small, but how can it be smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you correctly plotted your curve using parametric specification ? It should give you something like an "infinite" symbol $\infty$ as seen on this picture:
[image: cos(t/2),sin(t) parametric curve]

The total length will depend on $C_1$ and $C_2$ values and not on $L$ as you could use $t=x/L$ as a dummy variable and still obtain the same curve. Try to compute
$$ds = \sqrt{dy^2 + dz^2}$$ and express it in function of $dx$ before integrating from 0 to $4L$ to get the entire length.